# Additive and multiplicative valuation

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)), the axioms of additive valuation and multiplicative valuation requires $v(a+b)\geq \min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ and $v(a+b)\leq \max\{v(a),v(b)\}$, with equality **if $v(a)\neq v(b)$**.

What goes wrong if we are not necessarily allow the equality with $v(a)\neq v(b)$? (I mean $v(a+b)>\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ and $v(a)\neq v(b)$)

Well, if $v$ is an additive valuation, $v(a)\neq v(b)$, and $v(a+b)>\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$, if we assume $v(a)=\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$,hence $v(\frac{a+b}{a})>0$, Where is the contradiction? And the same for multiplicative valuation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assume $v$ only satisfies the “infinity axiom”, $v(xy)=v(x)+v(y)$ and $v(x+y) \geq \mathrm{min}(v(x),v(y))$ for all $x,y$. Let $a,b$ be with $v(a) < v(b)$. Then $v(a+b) \geq v(a)$. But $a=(a+b)+(-b)$ so that $v(a)$ is no less than $v(a+b)$ or $v(-b)=v(-1)+v(b)$. As $v(-1)=0$ (because $v(1)=0$ is its double and $v$ is valued in a totally ordered group), it follows $v(a) \geq v(a+b)$, so $v(a)=v(a+b)$.

Comment: @Mindlack you actually say that it isn’t axiom and we can get this equality by the axioms…. Very nice.